# Refreshing EF data binding in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I use Entity Framework `ObjectResult` coming from `Execute` method to bind data to a WPF control, like here:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Windows;
using System.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Edm
{
 /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for SalesOrders.xaml
     /// </summary>
    public partial class SalesOrders : Window
    {
        private AdventureWorksEntities context;
        private int customerId = 277;

    private void SalesOrdersForm_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate the ObjectContext.
        context = new AdventureWorksEntities();

        // Define a query that returns orders for a customer.
        // Because lazy loading is on by default, SalesOrderDetails
        // related to a SalesOrderHeader will be loaded when the query
        // is executed.
        var query = from o in context.SalesOrderHeaders
                     where o.CustomerID == customerId
                     select o;

        // Execute the query and bind the result to the OrderItems control.
        this.orderItemsGrid.DataContext = ((ObjectQuery)query).Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    public SalesOrders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

The example comes from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716735.aspx)

It work fine, but how do I refresh the binding? Either programmatically or when database changes?

Answer (score 0):

The SalesOrdersForm_Loaded code should be seperated from this event.

Place this code in a function. and call it in form load. Now you can call this function on your requirement basis.

I hope it makes sense.

Edit

You can call this function on button click / Timer or any event based on your requirement to update the bindings